# How to Overlap Components in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm just starting out with Angular, and I'm working on creating a sample site.

So basically I've got a cover page component called `<app-coverpage>` and I've got all the other components I want to add that I want to be overlapping the coverpage as its supposed to be like a background.

I've added the components into my `app.component.html` file and when I have them in the following order:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-coverpage></app-coverpage>
```

what I see is something like this

[image: this]

what I want is for the black `app-coverpage` component to be the 'background' for everything else.

Can anyone help me with this please?

On a side note. I noticed that I can't add this component to the `index.html` file. Meaning it doesn't render on my browser when I add it in the following way:

```
<app-root></app-root>
<app-coverpage></app-coverpage>
```

Can anyone please explain this to me too?

Thanks in advance for your help on both queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this -

```
<app-coverpage>
    <app-header></app-header>
</app-coverpage>
```

Answer (score 3):

> `<app-root></app-root> 
>   <app-coverpage></app-coverpage>`

No this will not work in index.html, because Index.html file will only encounter one component which is bootstraped (Entry component only).

To overlap you can add your `<app-header></app-header>` within the `<app-coverpage></app-coverpage>` component's template, and adjust using css as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Pardeep Jain! This worked for me perfectly!